# AS3 - Flash Pro CS6 - Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, object-reference

I'm working on a college project to create a top down shooter game in AS3, I have very little knowledge of AS3 but still have to produce a finished game. The game complies and runs but when I shoot an enemy I get this error

**`bullet hit baddie 2` <--- This is a trace element** 
`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`
    `at Enemy/removeSelf()`
    `at Bullet/loop()`
    `at Main/loop()`

Any help at all is greatly appreciated, many thanks. I'll post my code below so it can be referenced to.

**Main.as**

```
package
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var player:Player;
    public var enemy:Enemy;

    public var bulletList:Array = [];

    public var mousePressed:Boolean = false; //keeps track of whether the mouse is currently pressed down
    public var delayCounter:int = 0; //this adds delay between the shots
    public var delayMax:int = 7; //change this number to shoot more or less rapidly

    public var enemies:Array =  [];

    public function Main():void
    {
        player = new Player(stage, 320, 240);
        stage.addChild(player);

        //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet, false, 0, true); //remove this
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
        for(var numBaddies=0; numBaddies<6;numBaddies++){
            var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(/*null*/);
            enemy.x = numBaddies*50;
            enemy.y = numBaddies*50
            stage.addChild(enemy);
            enemies.push(enemy);
        }
    }

    public function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        if(mousePressed) // as long as the mouse is pressed...
        {
            delayCounter++; //increase the delayCounter by 1
            if(delayCounter == delayMax) //if it reaches the max...
            {
                shootBullet(); //shoot a bullet
                delayCounter = 0; //reset the delay counter so there is a pause between bullets

           }
        }

        if(bulletList.length > 0)
        {
            for(var i:int = bulletList.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                bulletList[i].loop();
            }
        }

        /*for(var h = 0; h<bulletList.length; ++h)
        {
            if(bulletList[h].hitTestObject(this)){
              trace("player hit by baddie " + h);
               }
        }*/

        for(var u:int=0; u<enemies.length; u++) {
        Enemy(enemies[u]).moveTowards(player.x, player.y);
        }
    }


    public function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void //add this function
    {
        mousePressed = true; //set mousePressed to true
    }

    public function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void //add this function
    {
        mousePressed = false; //reset this to false
    }

    public function shootBullet():void //delete the "e:MouseEvent" parameter
    {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(stage, player.x, player.y, player.rotation, enemies);
        bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved, false, 0, true);
        bulletList.push(bullet);
        stage.addChild(bullet);
    }

    public function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved);
        bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget),1);
    }
}
}
```

**Enemy.as**

```
package  {

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Enemy extends MovieClip {

    public var bullets:Array;

    public var stageRef:Stage;

    private var enemyPositionX, enemyPositionY, xDistance, yDistance, myRotation:int;
    public function Enemy(/*stageRef:Stage, bulletList:Array*/) {
        // constructor code

        /*bullets = bulletList;
        this.stageRef = stageRef;*/
    }

    public function moveTowards(playerX:int, playerY:int){
        xDistance = this.x - playerX;
        yDistance = this.y - playerY;

        myRotation = Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance);

        this.x -= 3 * Math.cos(myRotation);
        this.y -= 3 * Math.sin(myRotation);


    }

    public function removeSelf():void
    {
        //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this);
    }
}

}
```

**Bullet.as**

```
package
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip
{
    private var stageRef:Stage; //checks if the bullet leaves the screen borders
    private var speed:Number = 10; //speed that the bullet will travel at
    private var xVel:Number = 0; //current x velocity
    private var yVel:Number = 0; //current y velocity
    private var rotationInRadians = 0; //convenient to store our rotation in radians instead of degrees

    public var allBaddies:Array;

    //our constructor requires: the stage, the position of the bullet, and the direction the bullet should be facing
    public function Bullet(stageRef:Stage, X:int, Y:int, rotationInDegrees:Number, enemies:Array):void
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        this.rotation = rotationInDegrees;
        this.rotationInRadians = rotationInDegrees * Math.PI / 180; //convert degrees to radians, for trigonometry
        allBaddies = enemies;
    }

    public function loop():void //we don't need to include the "e:Event" because we aren't using an EventListener
    {
        for(var b=0; b<allBaddies.length; ++b)
        {
            if(allBaddies[b].hitTestObject(this)){
                trace("bullet hit baddie " + b);
                removeSelf();
                allBaddies[b].removeSelf();
                }
        }

        xVel = Math.cos(rotationInRadians) * speed; //uses the cosine to get the xVel from the speed and rotation
        yVel = Math.sin(rotationInRadians) * speed; //uses the sine to get the yVel

        x += xVel; //updates the position
        y += yVel;

        //if the bullet goes off the edge of the screen...
        if(x > stageRef.stageWidth || x < 0 || y > stageRef.stageHeight || y < 0)
        {
            this.parent.removeChild(this); //remove the bullet
        }
    }

    private function removeSelf():void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`stageRef` variable in `Enemy` class is never set.
You are passing it in `Bullet` class constructor, but you are not doing the same in `Enemy` class.

Comment: Ahhh, how silly of me, thanks. I've passed the stageRef, and now the enemy clips are visually being removed on collision with the bullet movieclip but their still present as the bullets are being removed when they collide and they follow the player as they should be doing but not when their supposed to be removed from the stage... Any ideas here?

Comment: Could you make that last comment a little more clear?

Comment: ++comment above. No idea what is actually getting removed and what's not.